# Is Geeta transgender?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, kanchana

In the 2011 Tamil movie *Kanchana*, the main character Kanchana is shown to be transgender but after watching the movie, I am not able to understand whether Geeta is also transgender?

If not, why was Geeta's school's principal saying, "Children like Geeta..." in two of the scenes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm pretty much sure that **Geeta is transgender**, because I've watched the movie couple of times. [The movie's Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muni_2:_Kanchana) also confirms she's transgender.

> Kanchana is a transgender woman who was disowned by her parents. She is offered shelter by a kind Muslim named Akbar Bhai, who has an intellectually disabled son. Regretting that she could not become a doctor as she intended, she adopts another young transgender girl named Geetha and works hard to support her financially.

Comment: Wiki's shouldn't be taken at face value as they can be edited by anybody. Look for commentary from the director or writers. If neither one of them confirm it then it's not the case